# Vimscript - Invalid argument in function declaration

Tags: vimscript

I'm learning some Vimscript code from here .

And the next lines will not compile:

```
function! Mapped(fn ,l)
     let new_list = deepcopy(a:l)
     call map(new_list, string(a:fn) . '(v:val)')
     return new_list
endfunction
```

When I'm running `:source %`

I'm getting the following error:

`Invalid argument: Mapped(fn, l)`

I cant' seem to figure out how.

Comment: Did you tried calling the function in command line?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to call this function from command mode and it is resulting in "Unknown function "

Comment: You should remove the space between the argument `fn` and the comma: `function! Mapped(fn, l)`.

Comment: If it shows as unknown function, then your function is not in vimrc or .vim directory

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you want, but it seems the argument `fn` is supposed to contain the name of a function, and that you want to replace all items in a list by the output of whatever `fn` contains. If this is the case, I could be wrong, but I don't think you should use the `string()` function. You probably need a funcref, which you can get with the `function()` function. I'm not sure but you could try this: http://vpaste.net/96o2E You would use it like this: `:echo Mapped('YourFuncName', your_list)`

Comment: The space before comma is not accepted.  This looks like a bug in the parser, report it to `vim_dev`.

Comment: Yes this was the problem, I needed to remove the whitespace after fn.

Comment: @SatoKatsura It's a known problem and mentioned in the help (`:h todo` (search for function, I even posted a patch about it, but Bram didn't want to included it, since he didn't like the style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of a bug in `vim_dev` parser, the space before coma is not accepted.

Thus you must use:

```
function! Mapped(fn,l)
     let new_list = deepcopy(a:l)
     call map(new_list, string(a:fn) . '(v:val)')
     return new_list
endfunction
```